# Power BI Creating a Column for same Sale ID

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

My work has a new Ecommerce system and our sales enter our POS in a different format. Normally our online sales come from the store they are purchased and picked up from, but now the purchase has Ecommerce as the store and it adds an extra $0 product to the purchase and it is named as the store. For our reporting this is an issue because it still shows inventory leaving that store, but it doesn't track it as sales for that store. Here is examples of what a few sales look like.

| Store | Quantity | Revenue | Product Name | Sale ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ecommerce | 1 | $0 | Store A | 06543 |
| Ecommerce | 1 | $5 | Product B | 06543 |

And here is what a normal sale from our store looks like

| Store | Quantity | Revenue | Product Name | Sale ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store C | 1 | $4 | Product D | REG-100 |

I'm thinking of creating a calculated column in PowerBI showing if Store = 'Ecommerce', and if Sale ID is equal, then show Product Name. But I can't seem to format it right. I know it can be done I'm just a little stuck. If anyone could give me a hand I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below steps:

1. In the PowerQuery, create two tables: one for sales where totalRevenue = $0 (representing Store) & one for sales where totalRevenue <> $0 (representing sales)
2. Establish relationship between Store & Sales tables using Sale ID
3. You can get the store name using calculated column Related(Store(ProductName)) to get the Store